# list comprehension division

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

hello I am trying to divide two lists of distance and time differences however sometimes the time difference is 0 I don't know how to account for this in list comprehension.

```
velocity = [j / i for i, j in zip(distance[1:], time_diff[:-1]) if time_diff[i] > 0]
```

I get this error for this implementation.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

Comment: I think you mean `if i > 0` ať the end not `if time_diff[i] > 0`

Comment: you use ``i`` as an element of ``distance`` and as index in ``time_diff``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment said, in your if condition, you should add `i>0` because `for i, j in zip(distance[1:], time_diff[:-1])` gives you the element in your lists, not indices of the list.

```
velocity = [j / i for i, j in zip(distance[1:], time_diff[:-1]) if i > 0]
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight this was the solution to my problem I am a bit new to python and list comp so this was helpful.

Comment: @JaredCusick You're most welcome :) Also, are you planning to address the result when time-difference is 0?

Comment: yes I actually already fixed it because I realized in asking this question that I had them in the wrong order haha